# OnKeyPress works fine, but nothing happens with keyDown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the delete keyCode in a React app, but nothing is happening. I have `OnKeyPress` already working for printable characters, but I need to also detect the delete, which from what I understand, is handled with `keyDown`. See my code below. FYI, I have also tried `OnKeyDown`, just in case that was the issue.

```
  handleDelete: function(e) {
  console.log(e)
    if (e.keyCode == 46) {
        console.log('Pressed Delete')
    }
  },

   render: function() {
       return (
       <div>
          <input 
              onKeyPress={this.handleChange} 
              keyDown={this.handleDelete}
              value={this.state.value}
          />
          <h3>{this.state.value}</h3>
       </div>
       );
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your phrasing consistent, and use `onKeyDown`.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#keyboard-events